# Launch Activity not found RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo ClassNotFoundException

Tags: android

I am really facing this weird problem that my Launching activity is not found when I run the app but code and every other thing seems fine. I am using Android Studio 2.2.

I have also tried to run it with previous android studio but the same problem. This is the error log.

```
07-15 03:12:35.324 32248-32248/indian.railway.app E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: indian.railway.app, PID: 32248
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{indian.railway.app/indian.railway.app.LaunchActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "indian.railway.app.LaunchActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/indian.railway.app-3.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/indian.railway.app-3, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2313)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2500)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:171)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1309)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5679)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "indian.railway.app.LaunchActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/indian.railway.app-3.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/indian.railway.app-3, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:67)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1067)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2304)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2500) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:171) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1309) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5679) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107) 
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

My manifest

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="indian.railway.app">


<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />

<application
    android:name=".AppController"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"
    >
    <activity
        android:name="indian.railway.app.LaunchActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>


    <activity
        android:name=".PNRActivity"
        android:label="@string/pnr_status"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
    <activity
        android:name=".MoreOptions"
        android:label="More Options"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".TrainBetween"
        android:label="Between stations"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".TrainBwResult"
        android:label="Between stations"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".TrainSearch"
        android:label="@string/train_search"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
    <activity
        android:name=".ScheduleActivity"
        android:label="@string/train_schedule"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Wallet"
        android:label="Ticket Wallet"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".WalletPNR"
        android:label="Wallet PNR"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".BerthMap"
        android:label="Berth Finder"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".CurrentBooking"
        android:label="Current Booking"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

    <activity
        android:name=".LiveTrain"
        android:label="@string/spot_my_train"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".AvailActivity"
        android:label="Availability"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />


    <activity
        android:name=".LiveStation"
        android:label="@string/station_status"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />


    <activity
        android:name=".FareEnquiry"
        android:label="Fare Enquiry"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".CancelledTrains"
        android:label="Cancelled Trains"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".ReschTrains"
        android:label="Rescheduled Trains"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".DivertedTrains"
        android:label="Diverted Trains"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".WebView"
        android:label="Site"

        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />


    <activity
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />

    <activity
        android:name=".PrivacyPolicyWebView"
        android:label="Privacy Policy"

        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

    <activity
        android:name=".MyLastLocation"
        android:label="Last Stop"
        android:exported="true"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

    <service
        android:name="anagog.pd.service.MobilityService"
        android:process=":remote">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="anagog.pd.service.MobilityService" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <receiver android:name="anagog.pd.service.StartOnBoot">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <receiver android:name="anagog.pd.service.AlarmReceiver">
    </receiver>
    <receiver android:name="anagog.pd.service.StartOnUser">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <receiver android:name=".LocationReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="anagog.pd.service.intent.PARKING_UPDATE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyAE2NXCsOBlN-dr1HmMD8HZ0miu0EQh66U"
        />
</application>
```

My Gradle file.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.0"

    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "indian.railway.app"
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 3
        versionName "3.0"
        multiDexEnabled true

        ndk
                {
                    moduleName "HelloJNI"
                }

        sourceSets.main
                {
                    jni.srcDirs = []
                    jniLibs.srcDirs "src/main/libs"
                }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0'
    compile 'com.github.navasmdc:MaterialDesign:1.5@aar'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.2.1'
}
configurations {
    all*.exclude group: 'com.google.firebase', module: 'firebase-common'
}
```

Launching Activity

```
package indian.railway.app;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdListener;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.InterstitialAd;

public class LaunchActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnClickListener {
    private SharedPreferences sp;
    ConnectionDetector cd;
    ActionBar ab;
```

Comment: did you found the solution?

Answer (score 0):

android:name="indian.railway.app.LaunchActivity"

Change to

android:name=".LaunchActivity"